# Need help understanding how this grid works

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Inside the for loop you have a loop for "x" and one for "y". I don't get why you need both for this to work? Why doesn't one of the loops just keep appending "squares" until the "container" is full?

```
#JQUERY
function makeGrid() {
   for (var x = 0; x < numberSquares; x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < numberSquares; y++) {
          $("<div class='square'></div>").appendTo('.container');
      }
   }
   $('.square').css({'width': squareSize, 'height': squareSize});
}
```

Comment: It's easier for beginners to understand and you also have `x` and `y` ready which is nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this could be done in a single loop in your above example, I believe the **primary** reason that it was done in two loops here is for adaptability. Consider a use-case where the grid is not a perfect square. You could easily swap out `numberSquares` in the two loops for variables that define the width and height respectively. You also have `x` and `y` defined separately for exactly this scenario!

As a **secondary** reason, I'd say that using two loops provides greater clarity. If this was a single loop, you'd need to 'remember' the **total** number of squares yourself. For example, if you had a 13x13 grid, `numSquares` would need to be `169` -- much more difficult to remember than a 'width' of `13` for a perfect square, which can be re-used for both the width and height.

Hope this helps! :)